# LINQ to Entities - sort by array

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, icomparable, icomparer

I have the following code:

```
    public List<OversizeElement> GetOversizeRegulations(List<string> states)
    {
        var tmpList = (from i in _db.States
                       where states.Any(p=>i.Name == p)
                       select new
                       {
                           StateID = i.ID,
                           StateName = i.Name,
                           StateShortName = i.ShortName
                       }).ToList();
```

so, I select additional information for all states from 'states' variable. It works, but I need to get the same order, as in the 'states' variable. How to sort it? It requires IComparer object, but I can't imagine how to write it in my case

Comment: How is `states` ordered ?

Comment: is the order from states diffent then tmplist?

Comment: @lordkain, different

Comment: @MatiasCicero, randomly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the original ordering you can do something like:

```
public List<Destination> GetOversizeRegulations(List<string> states)
{

        var tmpDictionary = (from i in _db.States
                             where states.Contains(i.Name)
                             select new
                                      {
                                        StateID = i.Id,
                                        StateName = i.Name,
                                        StateShortName = i.ShartName
                                      }
                              ).ToDictionary(k => k.StateName, k => k);

        var result = states
                    .Where(m=>tmpDictionary.ContainsKey(m))
                    .Select(m => tmpDictionary[m]).ToList();


 }
```

Comment: Where does `_db.Destinations` come from?

Comment: @MatiasCicero Sorry,this is your Table (States) .I haven't compiled it,I think there aren't any other syntax errors..

Comment: @MatiasCicero I just added the final Where in case state now not exist in the db

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate `states` instead of `_db.States`:

```
var tmpList = states
              .Select(s => _db.States.SingleOrDefault(st => st.Name == s))
              .Where(s => s != null)
              .Select(new
              {
                  StateID = s.ID,
                  StateName = s.Name,
                  StateShortName = s.ShortName
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IndexOf` function within your `OrderBy` function. Assuming you have an `id` field of some sort in both lists that are identical. Let's say in this instance that id is called `StateId`:

```
var tmpList = (from i in _db.States
                   where states.Any(p=>i.Name == p)
                   select new
                   {
                       StateID = i.ID,
                       StateName = i.Name,
                       StateShortName = i.ShortName
                   }).OrderBy(s => states.Select(x => x.StateId).IndexOf(s.StateId)).ToList();
```